# Make button be in the MouseOverState

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

To make a button be on the press state I do:

```
Button myBtn = // some button in my wpf view
typeof(Button).GetMethod(
    "set_IsPressed",
    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic
).Invoke(myBtn, new object[] { true });
```

**what private method do I have to call to make it be in the mouse over state?**

### Edit

The reason why I need this funcionality is because I like the look and feel of a third party class library. When I use the library buttons they are stilled very nice. **I want to use one of this buttons as the background of my control** On top of that button I place a rectangle with opacity .001 so that the button cannot be pressed. I already managed to make the button be on the pressed state. **Now I need to make the button be in the hover state.**

Comment: Actually you are setting the pressed state and not the mouse over. Is Pressed is not a function but property setter. This property is used in the Button style to change visual state of the button. If you need the state of the button to be pressed the best way is probably to override the button class and to implement the behavior you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set_IsPressed is of course the set portion of the IsPressed property of the System.Windows.Controls.Button class.  And using your code will certainly work, since the setter is protected, although I am not sure about the strategy you are using.

However, the correlating IsMouseOver (as well as IsMouseDirectlyOver) property, which is technically part of UIElement, is readonly.  So it has a getter, but not a setter (and doesn't exist). As a result...

```
  MethodInfo mthd = typeof(Button).GetMethod("get_IsMouseOver");  // works
```

will return a valid method which may be invoked, however

```
  MethodInfo mthd = typeof(Button).GetMethod("set_IsMouseOver");  // returns null
```

will not be found.

Here is the IsPressed property in ButtonBase

```
    [Browsable(false)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    public bool IsPressed
    {
        get { return (bool)base.GetValue(ButtonBase.IsPressedProperty); }
        protected set {  base.SetValue(ButtonBase.IsPressedPropertyKey, BooleanBoxes.Box(value)); }
    }
```

Whereas here is the IsMouseOver property in UIElement:

```
    public bool IsMouseOver
    {
        [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
        get { return this.ReadFlag(CoreFlags.IsMouseOverCache); }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT:

Note that IsPressed is simply a DependencyProperty, therefore GetValue and SetValue modify the value, and the visual is updated.  However that is not the case with ReadFlag.

ReadFlag has the following implementation:

```
    internal bool ReadFlag(CoreFlags field)
    {
        return (this._flags & field) != CoreFlags.None;
    }
```

Corresponding WriteFlag:

```
    internal void WriteFlag(CoreFlags field, bool value)
    {
        if (value)
        {
            UIElement uIElement = this;
            uIElement._flags = uIElement._flags | field;
            return;
        }
        UIElement uIElement1 = this;
        uIElement1._flags = uIElement1._flags & ~field;
    }
```

Updating the _flags field will not have an impact on the visual until it is invalidated.
However I do hope you find a way to get that to work the way you want.
Good luck.

Comment: +1 thanks for the help. I am just going to wait a little more maybe there is a way of making a button have the mouseOver state with reflection.

Comment: Sounds good.  However one reason I included the property code is important.  IsPressed is simply a DependencyProperty, and is therefore modified with SetValue.  But IsMouseOver reads a bit from the CoreFlags.  I haven't tried, but I suspect setting that flag will not have update the button until it is invalidated.